# Not able to install android studio (Error code - 36)

Tags: android, android-studio

- I am using Mac
- I uninstalled Android Studio
- I am trying to install android studio again
- I downloaded a fresh package
- I am trying to drag the package into applications
- I am getting the below error and its not getting installed

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem comes from your Mac pc file system. Error Code 36 is somewhat of a rare error that some Mac users experience. Kindly try following steps and retry again

- Go to permission and sharing option. Make it to everyone.
- Also, make sure that your account has read access to the files you
  are trying to install.
- Now try to install the same files. If you are still getting the error code 36, go for the actual fix given below.

STEPS TO FIX ERROR CODE 36

- Go to Applications.
- Tap on Utilities option. Select Terminal tab. Within the terminal
  window, type the following snippet of code: **dot_clean**.
- The folder,
  that was giving error code 36 while copying, needs to be dragged to
  the terminal window. As soon as you drag that folder, you will
  observe the path of that particular folder appearing on to the
  terminal window at the end of the command.
- After going through the
  above steps, Click Enter.
- Now retry to install.
  Hopefully, you shouldn’t be getting error code 36 on your MAC PC now.